# I want to get value from listbox, tkinter

Tags: tkinter, google-colaboratory

When I click item from `listbox`, I want to get that value and print it to label.

I try to find out and I got function name `<<ListboxSelect>>` but I failed to get value. What I can do is just print out the value.

What I want is when I click item in `listbox`, I want it to be printed on label.

Comment: We can't guess why it failed without seeing a [mcve], along with the actual results and an explanation of how they differ from your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example for what you want to do.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def update(*args):
    a = lbox.curselection() #note a is a tuple containing the line numbers of the selected element counting from 0. 
    print( type(a), a )
    lb_value.set( countrynames[ a[0] ] ) #Update the control variable's value.

countrynames = ('Argentina', 'Australia', 'Belgium', 'Brazil', 'Canada',
                'China', 'Denmark', 'Finland', 'France', 'Greece', 'India')
listCon = tk.StringVar( value=countrynames )
lbox = tk.Listbox(root, listvariable=listCon, height=10, selectmode=tk.SINGLE,)
lbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
lbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', update)

lb_value=tk.StringVar()
lb = tk.Label(root, textvariable=lb_value, bg='yellow')
lb.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

You need to pass your `Listbox` selected item to a [Control variable](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html) that is read in by the `textvariable` option of the `Label` widget. Depending on the type of data in your listbox, you have to choose an appropriate type of control variable to use, i.e. `StringVar()`, `IntVar()` or `DoubleVar()`. My example used `StringVar()` because the contents of `countryname` are all string type.